# nan cost in tensorflow training perceptron

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a single layer perceptron (basing my code on [this](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py)) on the following data file in tensor flow:

```
1,1,0.05,-1.05
1,1,0.1,-1.1
....
```

where the last column is the label (function of 3 parameters) and the first three columns are the function argument. The code that reads the data and trains the model (I simplify it for readability):

```
import tensorflow as tf

... # some basics to read the data
example, label = read_file_format(filename_queue)
... # model construction and parameter setting
n_hidden_1 = 4 # 1st layer number of features
n_input = 3
n_output = 1
...

# calls a function which produces a prediction
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: example.reshape(1,3), y: label.reshape(-1,1)})
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "Cost:",c)
```

but when I run it, something seems to be very wrong:

```
('Epoch:', '0001', 'Cost:', nan)
('Epoch:', '0002', 'Cost:', nan)
....
('Epoch:', '0015', 'Cost:', nan)
```

This is the complete code for the multilaye_perceptron function, etc:

```
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 15
display_step = 1

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 4 # 1st layer number of features
n_input = 3 
n_output = 1 

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_output])

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_output]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_output]))
}
```

Comment: Can you share the implementation of `multilayer_perceptron()`? There's a good chance the problem is in that function. Another common error is setting `learning_rate` too high. What value are you using for that?

Comment: @mrry I just added the details to the end of the post.

Comment: @mrry any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Is this one example at a time? I would go batches and increase batch size to 128 or similar, as long as you are getting nans.

When I am getting nans it is usually either of the three:
- batch size too small (in your case then just 1)
- log(0) somewhere
- learning rate too high and uncapped gradients

Comment: Is there a standard way of batching things in tensorflow?

Comment: Well with that None in the shape of x and y you started it. I jhust guess your feed_dict needs some work. Check out the official documentation also at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#batching