# Tensorflow - Nan Cost Values During Training - Tried The Usual Fixes Without Success

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have already checked out these three answers on SO but they didn't really provide a solution for my problem, although maybe it'll help someone here to help me: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561959/tensorflow-cost-value-return-nan), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470802/nan-cost-in-tensorflow-training-perceptron), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368931/cost-function-outputs-nan-in-tensorflow).

I have made a change to my Actor Critic Stock Trading Agent to include many more technical indicator training features/columns in my dataframe, and am now getting `Nan` values as my cost function during training. Without pasting my entire code as it's quite lengthy, I will post some relevant sections to hopefully help someone spot what else I can try.

The main architecture of the agent that gave me good training results looks like this:

```
class Actor:
    def __init__(self, name, input_size, output_size, size_layer):
        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, input_size)) # input_size = State Size = 405
            feed_actor = tf.layers.dense(self.X, size_layer, activation = tf.nn.relu) 
            tensor_action, tensor_validation = tf.split(feed_actor,2,1)
            feed_action = tf.layers.dense(tensor_action, output_size)
            feed_validation = tf.layers.dense(tensor_validation, 1)
            self.logits = feed_validation + tf.subtract(feed_action,
                                                        tf.reduce_mean(feed_action,axis=1,keep_dims=True))

class Critic:
    def __init__(self, name, input_size, output_size, size_layer, learning_rate):
        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, input_size))
            self.Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, output_size))
            self.REWARD = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 1))
            feed_critic = tf.layers.dense(self.X, size_layer, activation = tf.nn.relu)
            tensor_action, tensor_validation = tf.split(feed_critic,2,1)
            feed_action = tf.layers.dense(tensor_action, output_size)
            feed_validation = tf.layers.dense(tensor_validation, 1)
            feed_critic = feed_validation + tf.subtract(feed_action,tf.reduce_mean(feed_action,axis=1,keep_dims=True))
            feed_critic = tf.nn.relu(feed_critic) + self.Y
            feed_critic = tf.layers.dense(feed_critic, size_layer//2, activation = tf.nn.relu)
            self.logits = tf.layers.dense(feed_critic, 1)
            self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.REWARD - self.logits))
            self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(self.cost)

class Agent:

    LEARNING_RATE = 0.0000001
    BATCH_SIZE = 32
    LAYER_SIZE = 256
    OUTPUT_SIZE = 5 # Buy Call, Sell Call, Hold, Buy Put, Sell Put
    EPSILON = 0.5
    DECAY_RATE = 0.005
    MIN_EPSILON = 0.05
    GAMMA = 0.95
    MEMORIES = deque()
    MEMORY_SIZE = 500
    COPY = 1000
    T_COPY = 0

    def __init__(self, state_size, window_size, 
                trend, close_price, high_price, low_price, volume_price, ma, atr, mom_price, 
                skip, stock_name, number): 

        self.state_size = state_size    # 405
        self.window_size = window_size  # 50
        self.half_window = window_size // 2

        self.trend = trend       # Open price
        self.close = close_price # Yesterday's close price
        self.high = high_price
        self.low = low_price
        self.volume = volume_price

        self.ma = ma            # Moving Average
        self.atr_price = atr
        self.mom_price = mom_price

        self.skip = skip
        self.stock_name = stock_name
        self.number = number

        tf.reset_default_graph()
        self.actor = Actor('actor-original', self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, self.LAYER_SIZE)
        self.actor_target = Actor('actor-target', self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, self.LAYER_SIZE)
        self.critic = Critic('critic-original', self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, self.LAYER_SIZE, self.LEARNING_RATE)
        self.critic_target = Critic('critic-target', self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE,
                                    self.LAYER_SIZE, self.LEARNING_RATE)
        self.grad_critic = tf.gradients(self.critic.logits, self.critic.Y)
        self.actor_critic_grad = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.OUTPUT_SIZE])
        weights_actor = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='actor')
        self.grad_actor = tf.gradients(self.actor.logits, weights_actor, -self.actor_critic_grad)
        grads = zip(self.grad_actor, weights_actor)

        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.LEARNING_RATE).apply_gradients(grads)
        self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
```

So, basically my state size is currently a [-1, 405] array that gets fed to the `self.X` placeholder. Also note the learning rate, batch size, and layer size. This trains fine and decreases the cost function as it should.

Now, I've made a change that alters my `state_size` to be a whopping [-1, 2165] array from adding more features/technical indicators to my dataframe (as well as being a 60 period window size/lookback period).

From the direction of others and from the answers I've found online already, I've tried to:

1. Decrease the learning rate (I've tried a range from 0.0000001 to 0.00000000000000000000000000001)
2. Increase the batch size (I've tried 32, 64, 128, 256, and 512 with combos of learning rates above)
3. Increase the layer size of the model (I've tried 256, 512, 1024 and 2048, trying a batch of 256 and 512)

All of which returned nan values for my cost variable. Now, I lucked out and got a different error using:

```
    LEARNING_RATE = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    BATCH_SIZE = 256
    LAYER_SIZE = 1500
```

...that said:

```
print('epoch: %d total rewards: %f cost: %f total money: %f prof:cost: %f winratio: %f averagewinner %f averageloser %f'%(i + 1, total_profit, cost, starting_money, total_profit/cost, win_ratio, avg_winner, avg_loser))
    TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

...so I tried to print out the cost variable before that line to find out why it was causing that issue now, but I couldn't replicate the error on my next training run :(

So I'm at a loss for how to investigate this issue further. What else can I try??? Would I need to add another layer to the model (and what would that look like)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AAAAAAND I'M AN IDIOT.

I discovered that in adding more technical indicators, some of them created Nan values in the head of my dataset. I should have been more careful in analyzing the new dataset before starting to train. This was my mistake.

I still wonder though, if there are any other suggestions for how to trouble the Nan cost values for others who might be having a similar problem? My suggestion would be to print out as many variables and placeholders as you can along the way to spot where a Nan pops up, and to tweak the above mentioned variables, but anything else? Anyway, thanks for making me work through this! Smacks head.